# How to tell if a script is run as content script or background script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In a Chrome extension, a script may be included as a content script or background script.
Most stuff it does is the same, but there are some would vary according to different context.

The question is, how could a script tell which context it is being run at?
Thank you.

Comment: If you're developing the extension, surely you can load the script in the preferred context?

Comment: @Anon.: yes I can, but I as I said in the topic I may need some different implementation according to the platform and I don't want to break my code because of those restrictions.

Comment: I agree with Anon.  This is something that should be handled at build/deploy time, so to speak.  You could write a build script to deploy two different versions as needed.  Checking at runtime each time is very inefficient.

Comment: Well, I highly recommend you to do some sort of separation in your platform for "extension" related API, and "content scripts" They are both completely different. It is not preferred to do what you have mentioned below. It is best to let your extension context host your api and through Extension Message Passing, to control the flow.

Comment: Actually the case is that I am writing a Firefox/Chrome hybrid extension, I need to use some `init()` function in my code, which incorporates XHR calls, in Firefox it's all right, but in Chrome I have to `init()` by XHR call in background script, and then use message passing in content script to get the XML from the background listener.

Comment: This is all well and good except if your models starting needing to do funky things.  I suppose you could extend the models a bit further but in my case it's easier just to detect context.

Comment: I disagree with "most stuffs it does are the same".  If you're trying to code a Chrome extension and a Firefox add on with the same code (as per your comments), then there may be some overlap, but for a straight Chrome extension, I don't see that happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I managed to work out this:

```
var scriptContext = function() {
    try {
        if (chrome.bookmarks) {
            return "background";
        }
        else {
            return "content";
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        return "content";
    }
}
```

It's because an exception would be thrown if the content script tries to access the chrome.* parts except chrome.extension.

Reference: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

Comment: this approach has two problems, one, it relies on try catch which is really slow.
two, there are three contexts in a chrome extension; extension pages, background scripts, and content scripts. this only detects to states rather than all three.

Comment: It return "background" even on popup page (browserAction page).

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a fairly robust version that worked in my initial tests and does not require a slower try catch, and it identifies at least the three primary contexts of a chrome extension, and should let you know if you are on the base page as well.

```
av = {};
av.Env = {
    isChromeExt: function(){
        return !!(window['chrome'] && window['chrome']['extension'])
    },
    getContext: function(){
        var loc = window.location.href;
        if(!!(window['chrome'] && window['chrome']['extension'])){
            if(/^chrome/.test(loc)){
                if(window == chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()){
                    return 'background';
                }else{
                    return 'extension';
                }
            }else if( /^https?/.test(loc) ){
                return 'content';
            }
        }else{
            return window.location.protocol.replace(':','');
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

[The best solution I've found to this problem comes from over here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16268002/4842857)

```
const isBackground = () => location.protocol === 'chrome-extension:'
```

Comment: Technically this can be any extension page (popup, options, extra UI), not just the background one.

Comment: That's true, but if you just need to know if you're running in a content script, then that might be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

The background service worker at Manifest v3 does not contain a window.

I use this as part of my extension error handling which reloads the content scripts, when i receive an Extension context invalidated error:

```
...

if (!self.window) {
  console.warn('Background error: \n', error);
} else {
  location.reload();
}

...
```