# Can js code in chrome extension detect that it's executed as content script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a google chrome extension that shares some code between it's content script and background process / popup. If it some easy and straightforward way for this code to check if it's executed as content script or not? (message passing behavior differs).

I can include additional "marker" javascript in manifest or call some chrome fnction unavailable from content script and check for exceptions - but these methods looks awkward to be. Maybe it's some easy and clean way to make this check?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To check whether or not your script is running as a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html), check if it is not being executed on a `chrome-extension` scheme.

```
if (location.protocol == 'chrome-extension:') {
    // Running in the extension's process
    // Background-specific code (actually, it could also be a popup/options page)
} else {
    // Content script code
}
```

If you further want to know if you're running in a background page, use [`chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage)`=== window`. If it's true, the code is running in the background. If not, you're running in the context of a popup / options page / ...

(If you want to detect if the code is running in the context of an extension, ie not in the context of a regular web page, check if `chrome.extension` exists.)

#### Explanation of revised answer

Previously, my answer suggested to check whether background-specific APIs such as [`chrome.tabs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html) were defined. Since Chrome 27 / Opera 15, this approach comes with an unwanted side-effect: Even if you don't use the method, the following error is logged to the console (at most once per page load per API):

> chrome.tabs is not available: You do not have permission to access this API. Ensure that the required permission or manifest property is included in your manifest.json.

This doesn't affect your code (`!!chrome.tabs` will still be `false`), but users (developers) may get annoyed, and uninstall your extension.

Comment: Unfortunately, such property exists and detected by `hasOwnProperty`. Trying to access it (just read) raises exception: "Uncaught Error: "getBackgroundPage" can only be used in extension processes. See the content scripts documentation for more details.". I mentioned exception catching in my post - it's a possible solution but it's very resource-ineffective, exceptions are expensive.

Comment: @EyeofHell Sorry, use `chrome.tabs` instead. See updated answer.

Comment: @EyeofHell I've revised my answer, because the previous method comes with a potentially annoying side effect in Chrome 27+.

Answer (score 1):

The function `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage` is not defined at all in content scripts, so alone it can be used to detect whether the code is running in a content script:

```js
if (chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage) {
  // background page, options page, popup, etc
} else {
  // content script
}
```

There are more robust ways to detect each context separately in a [module I wrote](https://github.com/fregante/webext-detect-page)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function runningScript() {
    // This function will return the currently running script of a Chrome extension
    if (location.protocol == 'chrome-extension:') {
        if (location.pathname == "/_generated_background_page.html")
            return "background";
        else
            return location.pathname; // Will return "/popup.html" if that is the name of your popup
    }
    else
        return "content";
}
```